# Got the AttributeError: 'FarmerClass' object has no attribute 'farmer_name' in the following code

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I am trying to work around autocomplete dropdown combobox which works fine with database. but when i try to fetch data after updating database in runtime I got `AttributeError: 'FarmerClass' object has no attribute 'farmer_name'`. I tried other available solutions but still error is not solved. as of now, typo and syntax looks fine from the reference code which i was following.

the class which throws error

```
class FarmerClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.veg = []
        self.farmer = []
        self.buyers = []

        self.fetch_data()
        
        self.farmer_name = ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.farmer_name['values'] = self.farmer
        self.farmer_name.focus()
        self.farmer_name.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.check_name)
        self.farmer_name.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.get_data)
        self.farmer_name.place(relx=0.028, rely=0.243, width=240, height=24)

        self.product = ttk.Combobox(self )
        self.product['values'] = self.veg
        self.product.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.check_veg)
        self.product.place(relx=0.028, rely=0.380,width=240, height=24)

        self.buyer = ttk.Combobox(self )
        self.buyer['values'] = self.buyers
        self.buyer.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.check_buyer)
        self.buyer.place(relx=0.028, rely=0.5237,width=240, height=24)

        #======================= Entry btn ====================
        self.entry_btn = tk.Button(self,Btn_base, text='Entry', command=self.entry_to_bill)
        self.entry_btn.place(relx=0.481, rely=0.525,width=134, height=24)
    
    def fetch_data(self, event=None):
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM vegetable ')
        for i in cur.fetchall():
            self.veg.append(i[0])
        
        cur.execute('SELECT rowid, * FROM farmers ')
        for i in cur.fetchall():
            self.farmer.append(i[2])
        
        cur.execute('SELECT rowid,name FROM buyers_avail ')
        for i in cur.fetchall():
            self.buyers.append(i[1])

        self.farmer_name.configure(values= self.farmer) # getting error here
        self.product.configure(values= self.veg)
        self.buyer.configure(values= self.buyers)
            
    def entry_to_bill(self, event=None):
        name = self.buyer.get().lower()
        cur.execute('SELECT name FROM buyers_avail WHERE name = ? ', [name])
        bnames = cur.fetchall()
        if bnames:
            print(f'buyer {bnames} found')
        else:
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO buyers_avail (name) VALUES (?)',[name,])
            db.commit()
        self.buyer.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.buyer.focus()
        self.fetch_data()
```

if i try without those lines, `farmer_name` looks fine, `product` gets values of `buyers` and `buyer` dropdown goes empty.
please ask if anything required related to question.

Comment: How did you call the class?

Comment: `self.farmer_name.configure(values= self.farmer)` what is the error you get here? add full details

Comment: you need to keep the order in which you have define the arugment and calling functions, `self.fetch_data()` should be after `self.farmer_name = ttk.Combobox(self)`  declaration
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch_data` function accesses `farmer_name` but you call it before defining `farmer_name`, which therefore doesn't exist at that point. You need to call `fetch_data` *after* defining `farmer_name`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Kemp for answer. all I was trying to trace out code after updating the db. one change in position of line and it works..